# Running on Selecting Generic iOS Device in Xcode 7.1 always fails

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7.2

In xcode 6.4, i was able to build Build the project by selecting "iOS Device" and can use the .app file to test the same using diawi.com, however i have just shifted to xcode 7.2, and i can see the new option of "Generic iOS Device" which i thought of replacement of "iOS Device", however when i select "Generic iOS Device" to build the project, it always fail with the below error:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `Exit Xcode` and `restart your mac`. `Start Xcode` and run project.
This works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried the same along with that, i tried un installing it and reinstall the same. However the issue stays.

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries ?

Comment: Seems like the problem is solved.Let me post my answer.